# Dynamic Highlighted content filtering using page property as filter

Tags: widget, filtering, sharepoint-online, caml

I am using caml for filtering highlighted content. My query is like:

```
<View>
  <Query>
    <Where>
     <eq>
      <FieldRef Name='Service' />
      <Value Type='Text'>Wi-Fi</Value>
     </eq>
    </Where>
  </Query>
</View>
```

How can I replace the value Wi-Fi with a page property used to filter all highlighted web parts on the page.
I have 70 pages and 7 highlighted web parts per page and do not want to have to enter manual filters for each high listed content webpart.